# Remove window from Alt-Tab-Menu

Tags: process, gnome, pop-os, alt-tab

I'm using pop_os with Wayland and I was wondering whether there was a way to remove certain processes from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu.

In my case I have a certain `gjs` process `@!0,28;BDH` which appears in my <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu and I would like to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding out who is making that window, process is wrong word I guess, alt+tab show open windows. Say `ps aux | grep gjs` in terminal or search it in Gnome System Monitor or htop and kill it, but check if it is some thing important. Or `wmctl -l` to find the window id and kill the window with xkill.

Comment: Hey, thank you for reaching out.

I have already tried to kill it by using system monitor but it doesn't work, it just restores itself. I think it's a wayland thing, so as long as i use wayland it'll just come back up. Simply killing it doesn't seem to work, so i was looking for a way to hide it from alt tab at least.

Comment: @SamuelFrost try this, [How to hide window from appearing in taskbar, Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646346/xfce-hiding-an-application-from-the-taskbar/798408#798408) [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks#Hiding_applications_from_the_menu)

Comment: i tried that, problem is that gjs is not listed in wmctrl. I think the os sees it as an underlying background program and not as a window.

This is the output i get when compiling `wmctrl -l` and you can see gjs is not listed although i can see it on alt tab

`0x01800005  0 pop-os organizer5.py - Programs - Visual Studio Code
0x00a00002  0 pop-os xubuntu - XFCE: Hiding an application from the taskbar - Ask Ubuntu - Google Chrome
`

Comment: That's odd, in my system, KDE Plasma (Kwin WM), it even lists root windows, marked -1,  `0x02000042 -1 artix Plasma`

Comment: I know right? Even when i use the searchbox it shows the windows wmctrl sees, that means gjs is not showing, it's only present in the Alt-Tab menu